# Can ReasonML be used to make native iOS apps?

Tags: ios, mobile, compilation, reason

By this I mean truly native, and only iOS threads, not one that has native and JavaScript threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know yes, check for example **[Gravitron](https://github.com/jaredly/gravitron)**, a game made entirely in ReasonML by [@JaredForsyth](https://twitter.com/jaredforsyth) that compiles both to the native Android and iOS platforms!